# Can not test mailer action called in rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mailer

In mailer of rails, as I know all method will be class method.
But I can not test my mailer method called:

user_mailer_spec.rb:

```
it "should call send_notifition method" do
        @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        notify_email = double(:send_notifition)
        expect(UsersMailer.new).to receive(:notify_email).with(@user)
        @user.save
end
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
def notify(user)
     mail to: user.email, subject: "Example"
end
```

user.rb:

```
after_commit :send_notifition

private

def send_notifition
    UsersMailer.notify(self)
end
```

The above codes will not pass but when I change notifition to self.notifition, it pass:

```
def self.notify(user)
     mail to: user.email, subject: "Example"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd like to point you to an awesome gem for testing emails: https://github.com/email-spec/email-spec.

I think the problem is that you're asserting on `UsersMailer.new`, thus putting a mock on a different instance than the one then being instantiated by the `User` model. I generally test emails like this without any issues:

```
it "should call send_notifition method" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

  mail = double(:mail)
  expect(UsersMailer).to receive(:notify_email).with(@user).and_return(mail)
  expect(mail).to receive(:deliver_later) # or deliver_now, if you don't use a background queue

  @user.save
end
```

Note how I'm doing `expect(UsersMailer)` instead of `expect(UsersMailer.new)` and also take not that I'm asserting that the email is actually delivered (I think a deliver statement is missing in your code).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am sorry, I writed mistake. I use "expect(UsersMailer).to receive(:notify_email).with(@user)" but it is till not work.

Comment: Have you fixed the call like I mentioned? I.e. the callback should be `UsersMailer.notify(self).deliver_now` (or `deliver_later` if you want to use a background worker or just `deliver` if you're using an older Rails version).

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
Thank you @Clemens Kofler for supporting.
I have many mistaking in my code:

- First: No need to install gem "email_spec", and change user.rb file

from

```
after_commit :send_notifition

private

def send_notifition
    UsersMailer.notify(self)
end
```

to

```
after_commit :send_notifition

private

def send_notifition
    UsersMailer.notify(self).deliver
end
```

- Second: Change user_mailer_spec.rb file

from

```
it "should call send_notifition method" do
        @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        expect(@user).to receive(:send_notifition)
        notify_email = double(:send_notifition)
        expect(UsersMailer.new).to receive(:notify_email).with(@user)
        @user.save
  end
```

to

```
it "should call send_notifition_mail_if_created_new_hospital method" do
        @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        # I don't know why "expect(@user).to receive(:send_notifition)" not passed here
        mail = double(:mail)
        expect(UsersMailer).to receive(:notify_email).with(@user).and_return(mail)
        allow(mail).to receive(:deliver)
        @user.save
    end
```

- Finally: config mailer in config/environments/test.rb for test environment can use mailer (because spec run in test env)